# Can anyone help me find this verse in the Atharva Veda?

Tags: vedas, vishnu, identification-request, brahmins, atharva-veda

I have found this verse quoted many places, but so far have not been able to verify that it is from the Atharva Veda. If anyone can help me I will be very grateful!

> "A brahmana's house without a Salagrama stone is as impure as a cemetery, and any food cooked therein is as unclean as the excrement of a dog."

Comment: Also I would be grateful for any information about whether Salagrama sila was worshiped in all brahmana homes, or if it is still the case in India today. Thank you!!!

Comment: You can't find anything about Salagrama in Atharva Veda

Comment: It is the Puranas that has this kind of statements not Vedas. Specially in the Vaishnava Puranas or in Vaishnava Tantras you will find such verses.